# PHP sqlsrv_fetch_array problem && sqlsrv_num_rows -1

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

a new webserver has been stood up for me. It is Ubuntu 20.04 and has PHP 7.4.3 on it. I am working with MS SQL Server 2012. I can send my SQL query to the DB server and see it in SQL Server Profiler. I can copy it from the profiler and it runs fine in SQL Management Studio but, I am having a problem when I try to echo the results to my page. When I use sqlsrv_num_rows I get -1. Could I get a hand please?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['getPassBtn'])){
        #DATABASE LOGIN
        include './php/inc/dbLogin/mydb.php';
    
        #FORM POST VARIABLES
        $badge = $_POST['empId'];
        //$badge = (int)$badge;
        
        #check badge entry for paramiters
        if($badge == '' || $badge < 10000 || $badge > 30000){
            echo '<br/> ERROR : Invalid Badge Number <br/>';
            die();
        }
        
        $sql = "USE mydb SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT badgeNumber, userPassword FROM dbo.users WHERE badgeNumber = '$badge' ORDER BY badgeNumber ASC --getTestData.php";
        //$sql = "USE toolsMeskwaki SELECT * FROM bingoProgressive.users ORDER BY badgeNumber ASC --getTestData.php";
        $params = array(); 
        $options =  array( 'Scrollable' => 'buffered');
        
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params, $options);
        
        #check if query returns false
        if( $stmt === false ) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }else{
            echo '<br/> Query sent to SQL Server <br/>';
            
        }
        
        /*
        $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );
   
        if ($row_count === false){
            echo "Error in retrieveing row count.";
        }else{
            echo $row_count;
        }
        */
        
        
        #Fetching Data by array
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
            echo 'badgeNumber '.$row['badgeNumber'];
            echo 'userPassword '.$row['userPassword'];
            
        }
        
        
        #release query
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
        
        #CLOSE DATA BASE CONNECTION
        sqlsrv_close($conn);
        echo "<br/> SQL Server Connection closed.<br />";
        
    }else{
        echo '<br/> click GET btn to connect SQL Server <br/>';
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: FYI, your code is wide open to injection attacks. *Always* use parametrise queries. Also, I *hope* that `userPassword` isn't a plain text password, or you have another huge problem on your hands.

Comment: What is this `--getTestData.php` at the end of the query??

Comment: Do you really need this `USE toolsMeskwaki` and if you do, shouldn't it have a semi colon after it? ALthough does the extension support multiple queries

Comment: The userPassword has been put into the DB using password_hash()

Comment: --getTestData.php I added to the end so, I could tell the file that the script came from when viewed in SQL profiler.

Comment: @larnu could you provide an example of how you would parametrise the query so I could learn from it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You're submitting three different statements:

```
USE mydb
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT badgeNumber, userPassword FROM dbo.users WHERE badgeNumber = '$badge' ORDER BY badgeNumber ASC
```

It works in SQL Management Studio for two reasons:

- Auto-magic statement detection, although deprecated for several years (you're now expected to use `;` as delimiter), is still supported.
- The query tool is specifically designed to run several statements at once.

We know that [sqlsrv_query()](https://php.net/sqlsrv_query) supports it because it isn't returning `false`. But, given that you're running three statements, you need you use [sqlsrv_next_result()](https://php.net/sqlsrv_next_result) twice to move to the third result set.

On a side note:

- You can use [sqlsrv_connect()](https://php.net/sqlsrv_connect) to provide the initial database. You only need to switch DBs if you use several of them and you don't want to add the name as `mydb.dbo.users`.
- SQLSRV supports prepared statements (see [sqlsrv_prepare()](https://php.net/sqlsrv_prepare) and [sqlsrv_execute()](https://php.net/sqlsrv_execute)).

Comment: Gonzalez, Thank you so much! I didn't understand those were separate queries. I am now looking to implement the other suggested changes!!!!

Comment: @Soulcrusher I don't currently have access to a SQL Server instance, it'd be very useful if you could confirm this actually works.

Comment: I didn't need the USE mydb as that was in my include for the connection so, I removed it and the NO COUNT. This solved my problem and resolved that issue I was having. Thank you.

Comment: gonzalez, I can confirm using the sqlsrv_next_result() did move through the queries and display the results I was looking for. I tested it on a different query setup in the same way. Here is what was used

Comment: // Move to the next result and display results.
$next_result = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
if( $next_result ) {
   while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
      echo $row['recordId'].": ".$row['progressiveValue']."<br />"; 
   }
} elseif( is_null($next_result)) {
     echo "No more results.<br />";
} else {
     die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}